# What would happen if domain A redirected to domain B, which redirected to domain A?

Tags: internet

Is this possible? I can imagine that the endless looping would be problematic in some sense. What (if any) precautions are taken against this? Would it consume significant banwidt

Comment: Redirect at what level? DNS? HTTP?

Comment: By using the term "domain," you seem to be referring to protocols above OSI Layer 4, making the question off-topic here, but you could try asking on [sf].

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an HTTP redirect, browsers detect this and give up after so many redirects.

If you are referring to a packet level, this is called "ping-pong", and it's the reason TTL (time-to-live) exists in almost all routed protocols.